# Roteamento Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, htaccess

Estou fazendo um site com área administrativa utilizando o Framework Codeigniter.
Na área administrativa, o usuário poderá criar novas páginas para o site. O conteúdo da página ficará salvo em banco de dados.

O controller que lê as páginas do banco de dados se chama: **page**

Sendo assim, quando as páginas são criadas, atualmente elas são acessadas assim:

- www.site.com.br/**page**/pagina1
- www.site.com.br/**page**/pagina2

Minha dúvida:
Tem como suprimir a palavra "page" da URL utilizando o URI Routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma para um roteamento dinâmico é utilizando o banco de dados e, fazer com que o arquivo `routes` leia a tabela.

Este [link](http://osvaldas.info/smart-database-driven-routing-in-codeigniter) demonstra como pode ser feito no CodeIgniter.

Comment: Obrigado. Era isso que estava procurando.

Answer (score 1):

Routes funciona mais ou menos assim.
toda requisição que houver após do dominio, por exemplo www.site.com.br/**page** ele trata como controller.

ou seja, se você quiser suprimir a palavra "**page**" seria mais ou menos isso.

```
$routes["pagina1"] = "page/pagina1";
```

em $routes["**pagina1**"] você substitui pela palavra que gostaria de chamar, e em "page/pagina1" você coloca o caminho, **page** seria o controller e **pagina1** a função.

sendo assim toda requisição ao invéz de digitar "www.site.com.br/page/pagina1" ficaria assim: "www.site.com.br/pagina1"

Comment: E teria como fazer isso de forma dinâmica?